# Why System library on MacOs using gfortran aren't correctly linked?

Tags: linker, homebrew, gfortran, apple-silicon, macos-sonoma

I am using a MacBook Pro with M1 Max processor, Sonoma 14.1.2 as OS and gcc and gfortran (reinstalled a few minutes ago) coming from Homebrew. I was able to solve several issues in the compilation process of a Fortran/C old software I would like to use, but now have the following error

`ld: library 'System' not found`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I tried to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/lib/gcc/current/"` to the PATH env variable, but I had no luck. I think collect2 is pointing to **/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib** and **/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib** which are not in that place, but I don't know how to solve the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was related with the standard libraries that aren't located in the default folder on MacOS. I simply added

`-L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib`

to the gfortran flags in the Makefile.